# Obsessed with a statement of Charles M. Schulz

Tags: meaning

***Sometimes I lie awake at night, and ask, "where have I gone wrong?" then a voice says to me, "This is going to take more than one night."***

My friends and I have been discussing on the above statement of ***Charles M. Schulz*** and have come to different interpretation of it. Would someone please tell me what the owner of the statement is going to imply by saying that.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schulz is simply saying that he has done a lot of things wrong in his life, so many that it would take him many nights of lying awake and thinking to remember each of them.

Answer (score 5):

The basic idea is that working out where the speaker (or thinker as the case may be) went wrong will take longer than a single night. The implication is that he has gone wrong on so many things that listing and understanding them all will take a long time.

I don't really see any other interpretation, it's just a funny way of saying "I have made many mistakes in my life".